# Call http using Angular JS

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I don't understand how to use Angular JS to make an API call.

I can make a post call using Ajax, but I would like to make the same call using the Angular syntax.

Using Ajax it looks like this:

```
$.ajax({

        url: "url",
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (result) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        }
    });
```

and this code works, however when I try to do the same thing with a http call:

```
$http({

    method: "POST",
    url: "url",
    headers: {'contentType': "application/json"},
    data: JOSN.stringify(data)
  }).success(function(account){
    alert("You logged in!");
  }).error(function(){
    alert("Incorrect Information");
  });
```

Neither the success nor the error alert triggers.

I have looked over other http calls in Angular and am unable to find a difference between my code and the other calls. What is causing my code to fail?

Thanks!

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Open your network tab and check the status of the request.

Comment: have you tried $http.post.... as per angular $http service[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http]?

Comment: why you stringify your data since you always have {'contentType': "application/json"}?

Comment: I receive the error XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'url' Request header field contentType is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Comment: @maurycy, I'm not too well versed. What does CORS refer to? How would I use jsonp? I know that the API is setup as I am able to access it using AJAX already.

Comment: that is because of your typo 'Content-Type':

Comment: @ABOS please add answer..Nice catch

Comment: other typo : ``JOSN.stringify``

Comment: It was the Content-Type, thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried these examples? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

I'd recommend doing it like this, if data is an object:

```
$http.post('url', data)
    .success(function(account){
        alert("You logged in!");
    })
    .error(function(){
        alert("Incorrect Information");
    });
```

Your object will already be appropriately formatted and stringified for you.

Comment: I tried this method and received the following error: POST url 401 unauthorized

Comment: A 401 error suggests that you are required to be logged in before you can access that URL and you are not logged in, as can be seen here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error  Is there a form of authentication that might prevent a not-logged-in user from accessing this method? It looks like you're trying to log them in, so, naturally they're not logged in at this stage.

Comment: The issue appears to be that the server does not recognize the data inputted for the user to login. Is there a reason that this form of data is not recognizable?

Comment: ... Try $http.post('url', data)[...] I think I accidentally asked you to pass in an object that had 'data' as a property. But if data is an object and has the properties that your API expects of an input object, then just 'data' is what you need.